# C# .net web.client(UploadString()) mimic CURL with no data

Tags: c#, .net, curl, webclient

My project requires a **GET** to a authenticate a user. 
**Here is the CURL I'm trying to mimic**

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "header1: headerData" -k -X GET https://url.com/x1/users/userSlug
```

**The C# I'm using**

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
var urlEndPoint= URL + '/' + UserSlug;

client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
client.Headers.Add("header1", headerData);
try
{
PopulatedUser = serializer.Deserialize<User>(client.UploadString(new Uri(urlEndPoint), "GET", String.Empty));
return PopulatedUser;
}
catch (WebException e)
   {
   PopulatedUser = serializer.Deserialize<User>(new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
 //TODO: find server log code examples for errors
 return PopulatedUser;
     }
 }
```

with the String.Empty, I get

> InnerException = {"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."}

I'm not sure how to handle this and get the response, with user data, back.

When I execute the CURL Command, I get back

> {
>     "status": "ok",
>     "code": 200,
>     "data": { "user": { "id":"thisguy", userFirstname: "bob".... etc

Comment: And your question is??? What's the problem/issue? Did you check both web requests with a debugging proxy like fiddler2?

Comment: and? what is the issue you're setting with the C# code?

Comment: sorry guys, I thought i put the error in it, just added it at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not uploading anything to the server, so you shouldn't be using `UploadString` - upload would usually use a `POST` or `STOR` (for ftp), but not `GET`, which is probably where things are going wrong.

Use `DownloadString` instead. It uses `GET`.

So, instead of:

```
client.UploadString(new Uri(urlEndPoint), "GET", String.Empty)
```

Use:

```
client.DownloadString(new Uri(urlEndPoint))
```

Comment: @JonnyP - did you check the headers, with both approaches? Again, a debugging proxy like fiddler2 will really help you with figuring out what is going on.

Comment: 10 points @DigiFriend , you were right with this answer and I suck because I made a typo :(

SHAME SHAME SHAME